# Android ViewModel LiveData Documentation

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I read the documentation but became confuse on some part.

> ViewModel objects are designed to outlive specific instantiations of views or LifecycleOwners. This design also means you can write tests to cover a ViewModel more easily as it doesn't know about view and Lifecycle objects. ViewModel objects can contain LifecycleObservers, such as LiveData objects. However ViewModel objects must never observe changes to lifecycle-aware observables, such as LiveData objects. If the ViewModel needs the Application context, for example to find a system service, it can extend the AndroidViewModel class and have a constructor that receives the Application in the constructor, since Application class extends Context.

This part is somewhat confusing for me

> However ViewModel objects must never observe changes to lifecycle-aware observables, such as LiveData objects.

Is this referring to this kind of implementation?

Fragment

```
class AboutFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var aboutViewModel: AboutViewModel
    private var _binding: FragmentAboutBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        aboutViewModel =
                ViewModelProvider(this).get(AboutViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentAboutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val textView = binding.aboutTxt

        //Observe changes
        aboutViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            textView.text = it
        })
        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class AboutViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val _text = MutableLiveData<String>().apply {
    value = "Foobar......"
           
}

fun setText(text: String){ _text.value = text}

val text: LiveData<String> = _text
```

}

Or this is what they mean `LiveData<LiveData<Object>>` not to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means you should never use `observe` on a livedata object in your viewmodel, only in activity/fragment like you are already doing

Comment: can you give what is an example of that?

Comment: example of what

Comment: so no `observe` inside `ViewModel` itself?

Comment: instead of your `text.observe` being in your fragment it would be in your viewmodel. Thats what you dont want to do

Comment: example of the `Dos and Don'ts`

Comment: So no to `observe` inside of any `ViewModel` is that correct?